# Managing mulitple apps/ecosystem.config.js files with pm2

Tags: ansible, pm2

I am building a project which will live on a **single server** that will contain **multiple services** running side by side. I am using **ansible** to provision the server to automate setting everything up.

Services running:

- Headless CMS
- Database
- Other nodejs API etc...

If in the future I would need to scale this project up, I would then want to separate the above services out onto their own servers which has led me to creating separate ansible roles for each of the above services.

**My Question:**

I am having real difficulty in working with pm2 to get my 2 nodejs apps running with each other.
I know that I can have a single ecosystem.config.js file containing multiple apps which would fit my current architecture (everything hosted on a single server). However this would be a pain later down the road if I were to switch one of my ansible roles to its own server.

Is there a way to deploy to production my nodejs related apps using pm2 management but in a way where they have their own configuration files and systemd service which I can define in ansible?

If I have multiple ecosystem.config.js files for each nodejs app, can pm2 mangage these with the default systemd service it offers when running:

```
pm2 startup
```

Or should I just write my own separate systemd services which I could then manually install in each ansible role through templates?

I'm really lost here and have spent so much time trying to work out the best approach to take so any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research on this matter I came across this super helpful thread on pm2's github. Basically it seems that for automation using systemd services is the way to go and not bother with pm2's startup (which does create a systemd service, but more complex to manage when using automation software such as ansible.)

I **strongly recommend you read it** if you stumble accross this question!

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2914